# CS50 Caesar : SEGMENTATION FAULT issue

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I'm currently taking the cs50 course and I'm having an issue with the problem set 2 (caesar).I tried running the code below but it gave me a **SEGMENTATION FAULT ** warning but I can't seem to spot the problem by myself.
Please what is the problem and how do I resolve it?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool only_digits(string s);
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int i,n;
    string text;
    n = strlen(text);
    string s = argv[1];
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (argc != 2 || !only_digits(s))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    text = get_string("plaintext: ");

         for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(text[i]))
        {
            char r, z;
             r = text[i] + k;
             while (r>90)
             {
                  z = r-90;
                  text[i]= 64 + z;

             }
        }

        if(!isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            text[i]= text[i]+0;
        }
    }


}


bool only_digits(string s)
{
    int i;
    int n = strlen(s);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm afraid there is some strange stuff in ``cs50.h`` and ``string`` is not ``std::string``

Comment: `n = strlen(text);` isn't text empty? So `n` is 0. This statement executes before you do this: `text = get_string("plaintext: ");`

Comment: To make this answerable we would need to see the source code for `string`.  However, asking for the length of a "string" that is not initialized seems suspect.

Comment: Note that you are using `strlen(text);` before `text` is initialized.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the command line arguments and input you use to reproduce the problem. Or even better, include everything in your program so that it doesn't need arguments or additional input.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's a `typedef` for `char*`.

Comment: Oh, brother ....

Comment: Your segmentation fault is probably here: `string s = argv[1];` You did not check if `argc` was 2 or greater until after you executed this code. Remember that `c` is not like an excel spreadsheet where the formulas recalculate after the data changes. Instead your code executes from top to bottom

Comment: @drescherjm it's not empty, it's worse, it's an unitialized `char*` pointer.

Comment: I see, I was not sure what a string was in this case. I know it's not `std::string`.

Comment: @drescherjm [Documentation is here](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/#c.string), but I must issue a trigger warning. Harvard should be really ashamed of having published this library under its name, lol

Comment: That CS50 thing is hilarious... https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_string... I particularly like the *less comfortable* switch, it always crack me up.

Comment: Move `n = strlen(text);` to after `text = get_string("plaintext: ");` move `string s = argv[1];` and `int k = atoi(argv[1]);` to the 2 lines before `text = get_string("plaintext: ");` to correct the 3 lines that are in the wrong place.

Comment: Okay, all ramblings about this library aside, @Okonjo : you are often using things before they are ready for use. You assign `s` and `k` using `argv[1]` before you check if `argc == 2`. You assing `n` as length of `text` before you ask user to enter `text`. Both of these can result in a segmentation fault. I can't check the logic of encryption, because you use too many magic numbers and I can't guess their mening, but `text[i]= text[i]+0;` definitely does nothing.